# Identifying compression method in PDF and FlateDecode

Tags: pdf, deflate

Im trying to identify the compression method in a PDF file, and the stream is using FlateDecode -encoding.

However, the data's header does not seem to be a zlib header, or is it ? What compression method is used in the streams data ?

```
11 0 obj 
<<
/Filter
/FlateDecode
/Length 542
>>
stream
0D 0A 9A FC 2C 16 E1 DB 
83 80 92 08 82 AD 7A A1

endstream
```

Comment: I presume that you did that conversion to hexadecimal of the bytes after `stream`. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: The data is from file "Portable document format — Part 1: PDF 1.7 - Adobe" and the first FlateDecode stream in file. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`/FlateDecode` means that there is a zlib stream following the end-of-line characters after `stream`. What you are showing in hex is not a zlib stream, nor does it contain valid deflate data.

*Update:*

From the comments, the [example file being looked at](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) has encrypted strings and streams. (See Section 7.6 of that very document.)

Comment: Indeed, it's encrypted. Which surprises me as they used to have an un-encrypted version there. That encryption apparently has been applied to prevent content copying. And it has been applied a bit non-professionally, changing cross reference streams to cross reference tables and resolving object streams but keeping the stream specific entries in the trailer...